# Google map distance search from identical distance and coordinate returns Multiple lat and long displaying at the same locations

Tags: laravel, google-maps

When filtering the distance from database, I am using the code in laravel, it returns latitude and longitude with same distance. I got 70 records with lat and long

```
const locations = [
  {lat: 45.54751323777401, lng: 11.555961059186444},
 {lat: 45.557462631330944, lng: 11.56596232017967},
  {lat: 45.567526076710675, lng: 11.575985354229996},
{lat: 45.57747006892407, lng: 11.58596910522868},
{lat: 45.58751529253467, lng: 11.595983158055154}
 
];
```

Markers doesnot appear. but when we use MarkerClusterer it shows 70 point but when we zoom it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf031.png)

```
const labels = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
   const markers = locations.map((location, i) => {
      return new google.maps.Marker({
         position: location,
         label: labels[i % labels.length],
      });
   });
   // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
   new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
      imagePath:
         "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m",
   });
}
```

when we zoom it and suppose it shows 11 place but when we click on 11 place it doesnot show although it need to be clickable, suggest us how to show the name when cursor

Comment: when cursor...?

Comment: mainly problem is " same lat and long at same locations" and markers doesnot appear, but when use mastercluster, it shows 70 records in same place i cannot add the title when cursor scrolls on the place

Comment: newLat = dataJson[i].lat * (Math.random() * parseFloat(max - min) +min);          
 newLng = dataJson[i].lng * (Math.random() * parseFloat(max - min) +min);     zoom the locations it shows 36 22 12 when zoom more 12 it shows 11 after this when i click on 11 it doesnot zoom

Comment: add these in your question please @Sandip